# Why JTextArea is not showing up in this code?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextarea, gridbaglayout

Why Jtextarea is not showing up in this code?
I tried to add a Jtextarea in jpanel using gridbaglayout.
The frame opens properly but there is no Jtextarea on it.
I couldn't identify the problem.Someone helps me please.

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    public class ServerTest{
    //object declaration
    JFrame f;
    JPanel p;
    JTextArea ta;
    JTextField tf;
    JButton b1,b2;
    GridBagConstraints gbc;
    //constructor
    public ServerTest(){
        //instantiation
        f=new JFrame("Server");
        p=new JPanel();
        p.setBackground(Color.green);
        ta=new JTextArea("Hello");
        tf=new JTextField();
        b1=new JButton("EMO");
        b2=new JButton("VOICE");
        gbc=new GridBagConstraints();
        //end of instantiation

        //frame task
        f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        p.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        gbc.gridx=0;
        gbc.gridy=0;
        gbc.gridwidth=3;
        gbc.gridheight=5;
        p.add(ta,gbc);
        f.add(p);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
        //end of frame task

    }

    //Main method
    public static void main(String []args){
        ServerTest st = new ServerTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: _but there is no Jtextarea on it._ But here I didn't find issue like this.

Comment: As with what @Satya discovered, the code seems to work fine for me as well.

Comment: Yes guys..you both are right..it's a foolish post.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer, there is...

[image: Do you see what I see]

Here's proof...

[image: Proof]

You might have better luck if you make use of the `JTextArea(int, int)` constructor and use a `JScrollPane`, for example...

[image: Maybe a better idea]

```
public ServerTest() {
    //...
    ta = new JTextArea(10, 20);
    //...
    p.add(new JScrollPane(ta), gbc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set some properties of the `GridBagLayout` to initialize the background grid of the layout:

```
columnWeights 
columnWidths
rowWeights
rowHeights
```

Also it is not bad to change the layout of the whole frame from `FlowLayout` to `BorderLayout`:

```
f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

you change your code like this sample and it will work:

```
//frame task
f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
GridBagLayout bagLayout = new GridBagLayout();

bagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0};
bagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{25,25,25,25,25};
bagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0};
bagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{25,25,25,25,25};
p.setLayout(bagLayout);

gbc.gridx=0;
gbc.gridy=0;
gbc.gridwidth=3;
gbc.gridheight=5;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
```

Also `GridBagConstraints#fill` property has a significant role on sizing the components when using `GridBagLayout`.

If you want to see some detailed examples:
[SWING - GridBagLayout Class](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/swing/swing_gridbaglayout.htm)

Good Luck

Comment: Your welcome. If it was helpful and solved your problem you can accept it as the answer by checking that green check mark.

Comment: f.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); has (JFrame) BorderLayout in API by default